# Good practice in Rails 3 Way of routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

In the routes file written by other coworkers I see stuff like this:

```
  match 'providers/:provider_id/scorecards', to: 'scorecard#show', via: :get
  match 'patients/:id/summary', to: 'patients#show', via: :get
```

so they have NOT defined any "resources" in the route file. Just like that.

Is it really correct to do it that way?

Answer (score 0):

`resources` is just an easy way of declaring the RESTful routes. However, they follow a default pattern. In the case of your coworkers, they have declared a custom route so the URL will look differently than the normal one. This could be for consistency of some of the other routes that they're doing or because of an external API or 3rd party application requesting a specific URL that they're having to accommodate to.

The first route could be presented differently since it looks like a nested resource

```
resources :providers do 
 resources :scorecards
end
```

The second `match` definitely looks more customized.

Comment: which one is better:  /providers/_idParam/scorecards  OR  provider/scorecards/_idParam ?

Comment: also another question: does each "resource" need a new "controller"?